# Open file in Javascript from user-specified file name

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a file in Javascript that the user selects from the local filesystem. I can get the file name but I don't know how to open it.

```
<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input id="archiveFile" type='file' name='userFile'><br>
    <script>
        archiveFile.onchange = function (e)
        {
            console.log(archiveFile.value);
            // open the file here
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need for the HTML5 `FileReader` Api, further information are there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

here is a polyfill using Flash: https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader

This is a very well-made article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files
it explains almost everything.

working example:

```js
function FileReaderCtrl() {
  var self = this;
  var field = document.getElementById('fieldFile');
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  
  self.readFile = function(event) {
    var res = event.target.result;
    var image = '<img src="'+ (res || '') +'"/>';
    result.innerHTML = image;
    console.log(image);
  };
  
  field.onchange = function(event) {
    var files = field.files;
    var reader;
    if(files.length < 1) {
      return;     
    }
    
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = self.readFile;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', FileReaderCtrl);
```

```css
#result {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  background: lightcoral;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
img {max-width: 100% }
```

```html
<label for="fieldFile">Select an Image:<br><input type="file" id="fieldFile"/></label>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `archiveFile.files` for `archiveFile.value`. The value of an [`input type="file"`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)) element is not a `FileList` or `File` object

> For historical reasons, the `value` IDL attribute prefixes the file
>   name with the string "C:\fakepath\"

`archive.files` would be the [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object, from which you can iterate the selected [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File) object or objects if `multiple` attribute is set at `input type="file"` element. For example, `archiveFile.files[0]` to view properties of individual `File` object

```html
<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input id="archiveFile" type='file' name='userFile'>
  <br>
  <script>
    archiveFile.onchange = function(e) {
      console.log(archiveFile.files, archiveFile.files[0]);
      // open the file here
    }
  </script>
</form>
```